# Seeding nested JSON data and making polymorphic associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, postgresql, polymorphism, nested-loops

I'm trying to import json data to populate a database that consists of volunteer organizations and volunteer opportunities.  I want to tag all of the organizations as well as all of the opportunities.  I am using polymorphic association for associating the organization and opportunity model to the tag model.  I eventually want to create a quiz that will gradually build an array of keywords that I can then use to compare to both organization and opportunities tags to return useful results.

I'm fairly new to this and I'm not even sure if this is an efficient way to do so.  I have a log of json data that I want to put into a postgresql database and where I'm running into problems is trying to seed the data.

Models

```
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tags, as: :taggable
  has_many :opportunities
end

class Opportunity < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tags, as: :taggable
  belongs_to :organization
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :taggable, polymorphic: true
end
```

Migrations

```
class CreateOpportunities < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :opportunities do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.belongs_to :organization

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end

class CreateOrganizations < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :organizations do |t|
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end

class CreateTags < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :tags do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.references :taggable, polymorphic: true, index: true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Sample Nested JSON

```
[
  {
    "name": "A Child’s Place",
    "tags":
    [
      "children-and-teens",
      "homelessness",
      "education",
      "seniors"
    ],
    "opportunities":
        [
          {
            "name": "Snack Packs",
            "tags":
            [
              "indirect",
              "group",
              "food-preparation",
              "homelessness",
              "ongoing",
              "one-time"
            ]
          },
          {
            "tags":
            [
              "group",
              "indirect",
              "office",
              "ongoing"
            ]
          }
        ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Aldersgate",
    "tags":
    [
      "seniors"
    ],
    "opportunities":
    [
      {
        "name": "test opp",
        "tags": 
        [
          "direct",
          "test",
          "recurring"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

So from this data, I am creating Organization objects by looping every object in the array, and then within that looping through each tag and adding it to organization.tags by shoveling it in.

When looping through each opportunity within each organization, I want to create that opportunity object and shovel it into organization.opportunities.  Similarly, I am going to loop through each opportunity's tags array, find those tags and shovel them into that opportunity.tags.

here is my seed.rb where I am attempting to do this and make the associations

```
tags = [...] #array of tag strings

tags.each do |tag|
  Tag.create(name: tag)
end

json = File.read('db/org.json')

data = JSON.parse(json)

data.each do |org|
  x = Organization.create(name: org["name"])

  org["tags"].each do |tag|
    x.tags << Tag.find_by(name: tag)
  end

  org["opportunities"].each do |opportunity|
    y = Opportunity.create(name: opportunity["name"])
    opportunity["tags"].each do |tag|
      y.tags << Tag.find_by(name: tag)
    end
    x.opportunities << y
  end
end
```

When I run
    rake db:seed

I am getting this error from the line where I'm iterating through the opportunities

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
```

but when I put in a binding.pry and step through, nothing is coming up as nil so I'm very puzzled

This might be so wrong and stupid and I waited so long to post this because I know its probably shit but I am just stuck.  If you have any pointers on how I can better accomplish what I'm trying to do or just general pointers on any of this I would so very much appreciate it.

**Update**

I have linted the json data and everything seems to be seeding, but when I go into the console to check the associations by going

```
Organization.first.opportunities.first.tags
```

I am receiving back only 3 tags: food-preparation, homelessness, and one-time so not all of the opportunity tags are being associated. Perhaps I need to assign the taggable type during each association...

Answer (score 0):

please put a check whether the file is read properly. may be add a `puts json` or something and the error is for which line?

there is a problem in your json array which you have given here!
there was an extra ',' in 1st entry's -> opportunity -> 2nd -> tags near "ongoing"

`[
    {
        "name": "A Child’s Place",
        "tags": [
            "children-and-teens",
            "homelessness",
            "education",
            "seniors"
        ],
        "opportunities": [
            {
                "name": "Snack Packs",
                "tags": [
                    "indirect",
                    "group",
                    "food-preparation",
                    "homelessness",
                    "homelessness",
                    "ongoing",
                    "one-time"
                ]
            },
            {
                "tags": [
                    "group",
                    "indirect",
                    "office",
                    "ongoing"
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Aldersgate",
        "tags": [
            "seniors"
        ],
        "opportunities": [
            {
                "name": "test opp",
                "tags": [
                    "direct",
                    "test",
                    "recurring"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]`

Answer (score 0):

The comma after "ongoing" on line 32 of your json is causing it to fail to parse. I assume that the error is coming from line 11 because `data` is `nil`.

I would recommend setting up code linting in your code editor. If you set that up for each language you write, your editor should alert you to these types of issues and save you lots of debugging time and headaches.